# How to get TrueType fonts to display in xterm from a .Xresources file?

Tags: fonts, xterm

I'm trying to get a decent (read: not standard X11 load set) font for using xterm on Mac OS X 10.8.  I like Bitstream Vera Mono and it is in a file `VeraMono.ttf`.  I have placed this file in my `.fonts` directory.

Now, if I do `xterm -fa VeraMono` it works great.  But if I put the following in my `.Xresources` file:

```
XTerm*facename:     VeraMono
```

it doesn't work?

Ideas?

Answer (score 11):

As grawity pointed out the resource names are case sensitive.
According to the xterm man page. Search for `renderFont` you may need to set a `faceSize` as well.
The following lines should work for your `~/.Xresources`

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: VeraMono
XTerm*faceSize: 10
```

Comment: Doh, don't forget `xrdb ~/.Xresources`

Comment: Note this solves slow xterm refreshes on AMD systems.

Answer (score 4):

The resource names are case-sensitive; you must use **`faceName`** as in the Xterm manual.