# Install TTF font on xterm (cygwin)

Tags: fonts, cygwin, xterm

I am trying to install a new font on Cygwin. Lots of websites give tricks for an old Cygwin where everything was inside:

```
/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF
```

Some say it's easy with this:

```
cp /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/Fonts/*.[tT][tT][fF] /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/ttf/
```

I guess with the Cygwin 7.4 fonts are located into `/usr/share/fonts/` instead.

I tried to run `xfontsel` and I have very few fonts installed. I would like to install DejaVu Sans Mono and Consolas. Is is possible? How?

Anyway, I naively tried this:

```
mkdir /usr/share/fonts/ttf/
cp /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/Fonts/consola*.ttf /usr/share/fonts/ttf/
xset fp rehash
xfontsel
```

But I still see few fonts with a pretty bad anti-aliasing and the TTF fonts are not visible.

Any clues?

**EDIT**

I also get errors here:

```
$ xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/ttf
xset:  bad font path element (#0), possible causes are:
    Directory does not exist or has wrong permissions
    Directory missing fonts.dir
    Incorrect font server address or syntax
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TrueType fonts with X are usually done using `fontconfig`.  One of its features is that it looks by default in the `.fonts` directory under your home directory.  You would use `fc-list` to list the fonts which are available, and use them with the `-fa` (family name) and `-fs` (font size) options of xterm.  (while `xfd` has a corresponding `-fa` option, `xfontsel` does *not*).

`xset` on the other hand, looks for bitmap fonts which are referenced using the XLFD naming convention.  You would use `xlsfonts` for listing those, and the `-fn` option of xterm.

These links discuss the `.fonts` directory:

- *[Re: [ANNOUNCEMENT] Updated: mscgen-0.20-2](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2015-02/msg00319.html)*, comments on Cygwin mailing list
- *[Adding Your Custom Fonts to Cygwin's XWin](http://mike.hostetlerhome.com/blog/2009/09/29/adding-your-custom-fonts-to-cygwin-s-xwin/)*
- *[How to get TrueType fonts to display in xterm from a .Xresources file?](https://superuser.com/questions/463414/how-to-get-truetype-fonts-to-display-in-xterm-from-a-xresources-file)*

However, from the example given it seems that you probably already *have* TrueType fonts installed, and that `fc-list` is the natural starting point.

Comment: Great it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

To install fonts in Cygwin X11 so they are available to xterm:
get a listing of fonts loaded by setup:

```
ls -d /usr/share/X11/fonts
```

The result for me is:

```
/usr/share/X11/fonts/100dpi     /usr/share/X11/fonts/OTF
/usr/share/X11/fonts/75dpi      /usr/share/X11/fonts/TTF
/usr/share/X11/fonts/cyrillic   /usr/share/X11/fonts/Type1
/usr/share/X11/fonts/encodings  /usr/share/X11/fonts/urw-fonts
/usr/share/X11/fonts/misc       /usr/share/X11/fonts/util
```

in my case something is wrong with "misc" and "encodings" so I wont use them

Put a script similar to this in your ~/.xinitrc

```
fontinit=$HOME/.xfonts
xterm 2> /dev/null &
start-lxqt 2> /dev/null
# Ignore these for now, but fix them some time
#   encodings   util 
for font in 100dpi  75dpi  cyrillic  OTF  TTF  Type1  urw-fonts
do
# (for debugging ) echo trying $font
xset +fp /usr/share/X11/fonts/$font
done
xset fp rehash
```

After that when you start the X server using xinit or startxwin and then start an xterm then the font selection menu works for some things but especially true type fonts.